# nginx uwsgi bottle postgresql psycopg2

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi, psycopg2, bottle

**My requirement:**

About 300 (field sensor-like) clients report their status (json string) once every X (say 10) minutes. They can only use "curl" to do the reporting . The API/handler on the server needs to parse and dump all those values into the master table.
A few users (usually less than 10) connect to the app from their browsers to check the status of the sensor-reports and may linger around checking a few pages (main status page, detailed report page etc.). There are less than 10 pages (think reports) that the users want to see.

**My setup:**

Web Server: nginx
App Server: uwsgi
Framework: Bottle
Database: PostgreSQL
Python DB Driver: psycopg2
Frontend: Bootstrap

**My code:**

Please note that I did not include a lot of error checking and other security measures that we have in code, simply because they do not contribute to this discussion.

```
import os
from bottle import route, post, run, request, template, install, static_file
import psycopg2
import customemailservice

@route('/static/<filepath:path>')
def server_static(filepath):
    return static_file(filepath, root='/webapp/ss/static')

# The URL that the sensors will hit to pass on their status report
@post('/logger')
def dolog():
    sensor_id = request.json['id']
    sensor_ts  = request.json['ts']
    sensor_ut = request.json['main']['ut']
    sensor_ploss = request.json['main']['ploss']
    sensor_s1 = request.json['main']['s1']
    sensor_s2 = request.json['main']['s2']
    sensor2_status = request.json['aux']['status']
    sensor2_rts = request.json['aux']['rts']
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=<dbnane> user=<username> password=    <password> host=<dbhost> port=<dbport>')
    except psycopg2.Error as pe: 
    print pe.pgerror
    curr = conn.cursor()

    if conn != None and curr != None:
        curr.execute('''INSERT INTO tbllog (id, ts, ut, ploss, s1, s2, status, rts) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)''',(sensor_id, sensor_ts, sensor_ut, sensor_ploss, sensor_s1, sensor_s2, sensor2_status, sensor2_rts))
        conn.commit()
        curr.close()
        conn.close()
    else:
        pass
        # The code here is irrelevant
    return template('Ok from {{sid}} at {{ts}}', sid=sid,ts=ts)

@route('/')
def index():
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=<dbnane> user=<username> password=<password> host=<dbhost> port=<dbport>')
    except psycopg2.Error as pe: 
        conn = None
        print pe.pgerror
    curr = conn.cursor()

    if conn != None and curr != None:
        sql = 'select t1.* from tbllog t1 where t1.ts = (select max(t2.ts) from tbllog t2 where t2.id=t1.id) order by id;'
        curr.execute(sql)
        rs=curr.fetchall()    
        html=""
        for row in rs:
            html = html + '<tr><td class="warning">' + row[0] + '</td><td class="warning">' + str(row[1]) + '</td><td class="success">' + str(row[2]) + '</td><td class="success">' + str(row[3]) + '</td><td class="success">' + str(row[4]) + '</td><td class="info">' + str(row[5]) + '</td><td class="info">' + str(row[6]) + '</td></tr>'
        curr.close()
        conn.close()
    # Pass the raw html table that will be inserted into the index template.
    return template('index',tdata=html)

@route('/status/<sensor_id>')
def getsensorid(sensor_id):
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=<dbnane> user=<username> password=<password> host=<dbhost> port=<dbport>')
    except psycopg2.Error as pe: 
        conn = None
        print pe.pgerror
    curr = conn.cursor()

    if conn != None and curr != None:
        sql = 'select * from tbllog where id=\'' + sensor_id + '\' order by ts;'
        curr.execute(sql)
        rs=curr.fetchall()
        html=""
        for row in rs:
            html = html + '<tr class="info"><td>' + row[0] + '</td><td>' + str(row[1]) + '</td><td>' + str(row[2]) + '</td><td>' + str(row[3]) + '</td><td>' + str(row[4]) + '</td><td>' + str(row[5]) + '</td><td>' + str(row[6]) + '</td></tr>'
        curr.close()
        conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run (host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, debug=True)
else:
    app = application = bottle.default_app()
```

**My Question:**

Given the requirements, is this a reasonable approach? Or, do you recommend I use DB connection pooling? I am a little confused about using pooling since I am not sure at what level (nginx, uwsgi or bottle) does my app code get duplicated (to serve concurrent clients) and how should I go about creating the pool that I can use across different threads/processes (each of which contain a copy of this app code).

Obviously, this is my initial foray into web apps (and even serious Python for that matter) and would like to hear back from you if you think there is a better (I'm assuming there are many) ways to skin the cat.

Comment: At your blistering connection rate of 1-10 requests/second, I'm pretty sure any framework would be fine with any database, so long as it's handled intelligently. Unless you really want to roll-your-own DB handling/ORM, what do the documents for your framework of choice recommend?

Comment: By electing not to use an ORM I notice you're writing a) more code, b) inefficient code, c) vulnerable code (SQL injection, here we come!). Use [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) if you want something simple. [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) if you want something powerful.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Nick. The user  connections are about 1-10 at any given time, but apart from that I also have about 300 sensors, all connecting once every 10 minutes. I will have to look into what an orm is. Will Google it shortly. I'll also change the SQL to avoid injection.

Comment: Bottle doesn't really come with any DB engine by default. But, maybe there are plugins for the same. I'll explore that too.

Comment: Ok, found out what orm is. At a glance, it looks complicated and looks like it has a learning curve as it is not SQL. But I read there are quite a few benefits to using it vs raw SQL. And, looks like Bottle supports SQLAlchemy. Will try to learn it in the coming days. Would you mind pointing me to done resources that describe (at a high level) how all these parts (nginx, uwsgi, Bottle,...) work together?

Comment: I don't know much about Bottle, but I'd maybe look at Flask docs if they're easier to read and describe how to mix it all together. Flask also is more common so tutorials will be easier to find.

Comment: Look at a tutorial (or couple) for either framework to start though. It should describe the parts and how they're plugged into each other.